# Recommendations for compact laptop

Tags: laptop

I hope this is the right place to ask. My current laptop has reached the end of its life and was wonderfully compact 11-inch (not a 2in1 or glorified tablet) fairly low spec machine.

I'm looking to upgrade to something of the same kind of size (i.e. small, mobile) but with a bit more power. Although I looked for 10-11 inch purchases to begin with I couldn't find anything that didn't resemble a tablet with a keyboard attached. Visiting stores I also realised that these days, slim bezel 12 or even 13 inch screens can be almost as small as my 11-inch machine, whilst advances in chip manufacture allow them to contain pretty powerful processors / plentiful RAM etc.

So here's the specs, followed by a rough price guide, I'm looking for. Can anyone help with some concrete suggestions?

1. Slim bezel, small machine -- 12 inch if possible, or a really compact 13 inch. Should fit in an across the shoulder bag. The length of a hand should cover the screen, let's say.
2. Minimum i3 latest 2 generations (or equivalent); ideally an i5 (or equivalent).
3. 6GB+ RAM
4. Ideally a 256GB SSD (if not possible I can make do with 128GB) -- this will be a portable laptop for remote work for the next 3 years.
5. Sound and graphics specifications are a secondary concern. No backlit keyboard or other "luxuries" required.
6. Ports -- the usual USB (C, if possible) and HDMI (I won't be difficult by asking for Ethernet!).
7. WIFI, Bluetooth etc, but nothing more specialised.

An ideal price range would be between £300-500, but given the right laptop I could be pushed a little higher. I realise I am asking for a lot for this price.

Any clarifications please let me know - and of course, I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the larger size, the Asus X515JA-BQ273T would be ideal. It is all in the ideal range except the size (15 inch). It currently costs €550 (now 465 pounds).

If you need something smaller, you can get a surface 7, but that is outside of your budget. The Asus VivoBook 14 may be a bit too expensive and a bit too big, but for the rest it should be ideal for you

Hope this helped, I couldn't find much smaller though. (Except if you can live with an ipad)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions and I'm looking into to the models you mention. Not convinced by a tablet or ipad, nor a chrome book, since my work requires a dual mix of Windows / Linux

Comment: I see, I prefer Linux/Windows too